# Can I get Jest test instance id or context

Tags: jestjs, integration-testing

Suppose my test setup has the following pattern:

1. Build a model for this test
2. Initialize some application based on this model
3. Test the functioniality in the application

As part of #3, there are some async functions which can be run.
I have thousands of tests and want to create a safeguard against leaks of async functions into other tests- in other words, developers who forget to await for the result

My idea is as follows - Implement an afterEach in a global context which would check if an applcation instance was created for this test. If it was, I can catch all open async functions from here, and throw an error

To do this, I would need to have a testId instance or test context to which I can register the app instance when creating it for tests.

If we were using jasmine and old ES5 syntax, jasmine has a userContext feature which would make this easy:

it('some test', async function(){
this.appInstance = createAppInstance(model)
...
})

afterEach(function(){
if(this.appInstance){
...
}
})

Is there a way to do something like this in jest?

Comment: No, there's no such thing in Jest. *developers who forget to await for the result* - this can be solved at linter level.

Comment: It's not exactly forgetting to await - I was simplifying the process for you.
Perhaps I can write a custom lint-rule anyways... thanks